# NSData initWithContentsOfURL reading not all data, but only on device

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I am banging my head about an issue I have on iOS7 development. I use the following piece of code to load an image from a webserver:

```
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someServer/someImage.jpg"]];
```

This works like a charme in simulator, reading exactly the 134185 bytes that the image has. Creating an UIImage from that data works as intended. 
Once I test the exact same code on a device (iPad Mini, iOS 7.03), though, it just reads 14920 byte from the same URL. Needless to say that I can't create an UIImage from that data then, creation fails and returns a nil. 
The read does not produce any errors (no console output, and also using the signature with the error output param returns nil here). Is there anything I missed around this rather straightforward task? Haven't found anything on the web on this…

Thanks, habitoti

Comment: Please don't use -initWithContentsOfURL: on remote URLs.  On the main thread its going to cause hangs.  On a background thread, there are still issues   http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/

Comment: It's in a separate thread, so far I hadn't had any issues with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you don't have any error, and something is downloading. Maybe try to read this response and post here (I guess it is html/text body)? 
You can use NSString method: 
+ (instancetype)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error;

Comment: You are right -- I was simply too tired already to see the obvious :-)  The iPad Mini used a different localization, and so the (loooong) URL was actually different in a small DE/EN portion. What made me blind was the server not sending an error, but just a 200 response with a 14k nice HTML page telling that this image is not available. So proposing to actually "read" the returned data shifted me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you use a library like SDWebImage to retrieve your image, it caches it and downloads the images asynchronously.

It also has a category for UIImageView so you can just call [imageView setImageWithURL:]; and it will load the image in when its ready.

Comment: Thanks David, but caching is not required in this case. It's a splash screen just shown once (if at all), and it's downloaded asynchronously.